# Symfony + FOSRestBundle (postfields in PUT method)

Tags: api, symfony, curl, put, fosrestbundle

I have my API Rest with Symfony (2.8.6) with FOSRestBundle and Nelmio for documentation.

All of this works perfect, on nelmio sandbox all works perfectly but when I use my API by cURL nothing happens when I try to update one resource.

```
$curl = curl_init();
$data = array('fax' => 999);

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => "http://".$host."/fr/api/users/1",
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'PUT',
    CURLOPT_POST => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data),
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        'cache-control: no-cache',
        'x-auth-token: ' . $token,
        'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data)
    ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);
```

In resume, I can update the "fax" field through the sandbox but nothing happens when I try to do the same with external php file in cURL

Any idea??? (the token and the URL are correct)

Thanks to all!!

Roger

**EDIT**

The solution (that I don't understand) is put the user agent... with this cURL all works perfectly

```
$curl = curl_init();

$data_curl = http_build_query(array('fax' => 123456789));

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => "http://".$host."/fr/api/users/1",
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT => "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36",
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "PUT",
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $data_curl,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        "cache-control: no-cache",
        'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_curl),
        "x-auth-token: $token"
    ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
    echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
    echo $response;
}
```

Through postman the command line is:

```
curl -X PUT -H "x-auth-token: 112233" -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" -H "Postman-Token: fa3ba9da-986e-4c66-f03a-1d7fe1842a8b" -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d 'fax=55' "http://".$host."/fr/api/users/1"
```

Thanks all again!

Comment: What is the content of the $response and $err? Can you debug theses variables?

Comment: In some cases, servers will disallow requests that contain unidentified user agents. In other cases, certain features will be disabled (in the past, I’ve come across errors about my browser being out of date). By setting a custom user agent, you can fool these servers into thinking 
that your cURL request is coming from a legitimate up-to-date browser. 
http://thisinterestsme.com/php-set-curl-user-agent/

Comment: Thank you for your time @MohamedBenHENDA

Answer (score 0):

Try to execute curl in command line:

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -X PUT -d '{"fax":999}' http://yourhost/fr/api/users/1
```